# Dependency Inject one bean into other using annotation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I have following spring annotation based configuration:

```
@Bean
public MarshallingMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
    return new MarshallingMessageConverter();
}
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    return new Jaxb2Marshaller();
}
```

I need to inject `jaxb2Marshaller` to `marshallingMessageConverter` using setter based injection before `marshallingMessageConverter` is initialized by Spring. After lot of Googling still can not find this kind of scenario. Please help !!

UPDATE: I don't have have access to both classes as they are inside a jar file. When I Autowire them in a third class something like:

```
@Autorwired MarshallingMessageConverter converter;  //I need something like @Autorwired(setMarshaller = jaxb2Marshaller) where setMarshaller is the setter inside `MarshallingMessageConverter`

@Autowired Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;
```

Comment: Spring has multiple ways to achieve IOC, using annotation Autowired in the consumer is my favourite, try (at)Autowired private Jaxb2Marshaller  jaxb2Marshaller.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the `marshaller` to the converter constructor? If so, you can use the autowired to create the marshaller and then in the method annotated with @Bean you pass in the constructor:

```
@Autowired Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

@Bean
public MarshallingMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter() {
    return new MarshallingMessageConverter(marshaller);
}
```

Comment: Its setter based injection. I can not invoke "new MarshallingMessageConverter(marshaller)". Also, if I'd have such constructor still it won't be possible as by the time I get the Autowired instance of marshaller spring context would be initialized and I want MarshallingMessageConverter to have that instance before that.

Comment: I did not see any annotation for that. It is possible to pass the marshaller via XML or using that example that @dunni posted. If the MarshallingMessageConverter bean can be declared via XML, set the `<property name="marshaller" ref="yourJaxb2MarshallerBean"`>.

Comment: I exactly want to do <property name="marshaller" ref="yourJaxb2MarshallerBean"> only but via annotation. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public MarshallingMessageConverter marshallingMessageConverter(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    MarshallingMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingMessageConverter();
    converter.whatEverMethodCallIsNeeded(marshaller);
    return converter;
}
```